# Theorem content right after theorem name in beamer

Tags: beamer, theorems

When we write a theorem in beamer, by default the theorem name and theorem content are in different lines, like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------
|Theorem 1
|-------------------------------------------
|Some theorem content.
|-------------------------------------------
```

How to make the theorem name and theorem content show in the same line? like this:

```
|---------------------------------------------
|Theorem 1: Some theorem content.
|---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your current usage of a `theorem` environment in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) provides a means to modify the start and end of a `theorem` environment by setting the appropriate template. The start of the `theorem` environment template is defined within `theorem begin`, and the end in the template `theorem end`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
  \inserttheoremheadfont% \bfseries
  \inserttheoremname \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  \inserttheorempunctuation
  \normalfont
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
  % empty
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}[Theorem name]
    This is a very important theorem and requires an exceptional proof.
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\inserttheoremheadfont` formats the header as `\bfseries`. If you want to modify this (and add some colour or perhaps even a different style (`\itshape`, say), input it directly as needed. Ending in `\normalfont` switches back to the normal font shape for typesetting the remainder of the `theorem` content. `\inserttheoremname` inserts `Theorem`, while `\inserttheoremnumber` inserts the theorem number. Whatever is specified as the optional argument to `theorem` is considered as a "theorem addition", and is inserted using `\inserttheoremaddition`. Punctuation, if any, is provided by `\insertpunctuation` (default is a period `.`).

The redefinition of `theorem end` is also required. In this case, it is left empty.

Comment: How to modify this for `proof`?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: Try adding [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/NVdJT52E) to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I have another code running for continuous `proof` environments spread over multiple slides. A snippet of which is kept [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/aBmJbchu). And your additional piece of code is not going well with that. If this requires a new question to be posted, I will do the needful. Please suggest.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul: Yeah, I'd suggest asking a new question.