# No break line after theorem name in beamer

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, theorems

I have applied the answer of question [Theorem content right after theorem name in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/theorem-content-right-after-theorem-name-in-beamer) to my question.  I put \normalfont after \inserttheorempunctuation but the result is unexpected. Could you please see the image 1.

```
            \documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
            \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
            \usefonttheme{serif}
            \makeatletter
            \setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
            {%
                \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
                    {%
                        \inserttheoremheadfont
                        \inserttheoremname
                        \inserttheoremnumber
                        \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
                        \inserttheorempunctuation
                        \normalfont
                    }
                }
                \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
            \makeatother


             \begin{document}
                \section{ABC}
                \begin{frame}
                    \begin{theorem}[ABC]
                        This is a theorem
                    \end{theorem}
                \end{frame}
             \end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

I would like to put the content right after **Theorem** (no break line). It looks like this

[image]

Comment: This is the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203483/no-break-line-after-theorem-name-in-beamer, which have been deleted by the OP some minutes ago.

Comment: I just posted again my question. This question is not duplicate with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/theorem-content-right-after-theorem-name-in-beamer. I think that everybody can see it and help me.

Comment: Of course we see -- I don't think, that reposting it again will prevent it from being marked as *duplicate* again.

Comment: The other question was closed since there is already a solution to your question which can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/theorem-content-right-after-theorem-name-in-beamer. If this solution does not fit your needs, please clearify why this is the case.

Comment: This linked post uses a "clean" `theorem begin`, while the OP here uses an `inserttheoremblockenv` - the culprit that inserts the line-break.

Comment: If I delete \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv} and \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}, it will work. However, I would like to put theorem environment in block environment. It will be nicer

Answer (score 4):

You need to put your formatting commands in to the body, rather than the title, of the `theoremblockenv` and select the `block title` font and colour for the heading elements to mimic the style you ask for.  Compare with the two examples of blocks with and without titles.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  \normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{ABC}

\begin{frame}

  \begin{theorem}[ABC]
    This is a theorem
  \end{theorem}

  Text.

  \begin{block}{Block title}
    A block with title.
  \end{block}

  Text.

  \begin{block}{}
    A block without title.
  \end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```