# beamer and theorem vertical spacing

Tags: beamer

Is there any chance to change the vertical spacing in theorems when using beamer? The space I am talking about is between the word "Theorem" or "Definition" and the first line in the theorem.

And also, how to force text to continue right after the word "Theorem" without making the newline?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the block: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203531/no-break-line-after-theorem-name-in-beamer