Beamer block with title on the same line as content
I have a beamer document:
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}
\definecolor{blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=fondo,fg=blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{block}{Idea}
We have A.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Could you elaborate on how to start the first sentence We have A in the same line as the title Idea? I would like to have something like


duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203531/no-break-line-after-theorem-name-in-beamer

@Stephen The environment in your linked question is theorem which is not block environment.

@Akira A theorem is just a beamer block with a bit of extra formatting.  You could redefine the block environment in the same way as in the linked answer.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Almost every command in the linked answer has the term theorem (e.g. \inserttheoremblockenv, \inserttheoremname, \inserttheoremnumber, \inserttheoremaddition, \inserttheoremaddition, \inserttheorempunctuation), which makes me unable to adapt it to my situation.

@Akira What you actually want ? A block environment or a theorem environent ?

@zpding A block environment. I already have a customized theorem environment.

\documentclass{beamer}

\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}
\definecolor{blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=fondo,fg=blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body,shadow=true]%
    {}%
    \raggedright{\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle~}\usebeamerfont{block body}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Idea}
We have A.
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



Is it necessary to use \raggedright two times?

@Stephen Not particularly :)

An answer about how to set a new block style:
\documentclass{beamer}
\definecolor{fondo}{HTML}{e6e6e6}
\definecolor{blendedblue}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=fondo,fg=blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=fondo,fg=black}

% new block begin template
\defbeamertemplate{block begin}{NewStyle}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}{}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[NewStyle]


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
AAA
\begin{block}{Idea}
The set of natural numbers is infinite.
\end{block}
BBB

\begin{theorem}[Kummer, 1992]
The set of natural numbers is infinite.
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

The output:

