# Colored text for a theorem statement in beamer poster

Tags: color, theorems, beamerposter

I'm using a modified version of the template found [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/beamerposter---flow-multicolumn) and I followed the advice given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/theorem-content-right-after-theorem-name-in-beamer) to have theorems typeset in "inline" mode, instead of "block" mode.

What I need now is to modify the font of the theorem so as to be light blue, including the heading "Theorem" (or any other name for that matter) and the math. The code I've been trying unsuccessfuly is this

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
%\inserttheoremheadfont %\bfseries
{\bfseries \inserttheoremname} %\inserttheoremnumber
\ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
%\inserttheorempunctuation
\hspace{.01em}
\normalfont
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=blue!40}
 }
 \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
  % empty
  }
  \makeatother
```

I also tried with `\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=blue!40}
}` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87216/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-text-in-a-theorem-in-beamer) but I get an "Undefined control sequence: \AtBeginEnvironment" error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor*{thcolor}{fg=blue!60}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{thcolor}% for the heading
  {\bfseries\inserttheoremname~}%
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else(\inserttheoremaddition)\ \fi%
  \hspace{.01em}\normalfont\usebeamercolor[fg]{thcolor}% for the body
  }
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{theorem}
  A test theorem.
  \end{theorem}
  \begin{corollary}
  A test corollary.
  \end{corollary}
  \begin{theorem}[Zorn's Lemma]
  A test theorem with annotation.
  \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```